# How to enable log in Magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, log, debug, magento-2.0.2

I can't find any settings in developer tab from backend about log in version 2.0.2

Someone can told me where to find it

Comment: Take a look at 'developer mode' see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: Yes, i already actived developer mode. Is it magento remove enable log settings in backend? I am testing version 2.0.2 in production

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the debug logging to use the config:set command to change the dev/debug/debug_logging database value to 1

**Run Below command:**

> php bin/magento config:set dev/debug/debug_logging 1
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope it help!